# PHP extended class event

Tags: php, class, reflection, extension-methods

Here's the code I'll be talking on (keep this in mind throughout this post):

File: index.php

```
/**
 * Base class used when created a new application.
 */
class App {
     public function do_something(){
     }
}

/**
 * Class used, among other things, to manage all apps.
 */
class Apps {
    public static function _init(){
        foreach(glob('apps/*') as $dir)
            if(file_exists($dir.'/index.php')
                include_once($dir.'/index.php');
    }
}
Apps::_init();
```

File: MyApp/index.php

```
class MyApp extends App {
     /**
      * This function overrides the the one in App...
      */
     public function do_something(){
     }
}
```

So, you probably know what I'm doing; it's an application/extension system, were an application is kept in a separate folder in `/apps/` and it's entry point is `index.php`.

The code, so far, works nicely (or, well it should, I wrote it off the top of my head ;)).
Anyway, my issue is to make Apps class aware of all the extended App classes.

---

The easy way would be to write something like the following at the end of each application's `index.php`.

```
Apps::register('MyApp'); // for MyApp application
```

The problem with it is that although it's understandable, it is not automated.
For instance, copy+pasting an application needs that modification, and new developers are more likely to completely forget that code (and even worse, most of the code still works without it!).

Another idea was to use this code after the code in `_init()`:

```
$apps=array();
foreach(get_declared_classes() as $class)
    if(array_search('App',class_parents($class))!==false)
        $apps[]=$class;
```

But it sounds too resource-intensive that last one.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The register approach is okay, you could do

```
Apps::register(get_class());
```

inside the `MyApp` constructor, if you have one.

Comment: If you want to register every one, you can also put it in the `App` class constructor, though you'd need to remember to pass `$this` to the `get_class` method (`Apps::register(get_class($this));`), and you'd need to remember to call `parent::__construct()` in each child class constructor if you needed to add anything else in the constructor.

Comment: Aether...that's exactly what I needed! You should have made it into an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The register approach looks clean and simple. It will be clear to later maintainers (and to yourself) what the code does and it's less error-prone.

Comment: Actually, I feel it's more error prone and a hassle to maintain. But that's just about all I can think of against it.